# I want to integrate the VOIP audio calling to my Android application

Tags: android, voip

Is there any example of the voip integration to an Android app?
I want to call audio connecting to the user just give me the example of the voip integration on Android and is there any another way to audio calling please give me proper guidance on audio calling integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and tested a sample application for app to phone calling. Link here https://github.com/febimfelix/MyVoipCaller

I used [sinch](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/) library.

Comment: user can connect randomly or user have to dial the number and the he/she connect via voip ?